# How can I delete all the items in combo box?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, combobox

I have a ComboBox control with the DropDownStyle properties set to DropDownList. I want to replace the list of items with some new items at some points in the form but it concatenates the new items with the old items. How can I delete the old items and place new items in the combo box?

I am trying something like that:

```
        this.selectAttribute.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "Airport_Name", //New items
            "City",
            "Country"});
```

Comment: `AddRange` does exactly as it's named, it `Add`'s items to the collection, not remove and or clear the existing items out. Have you tried researching on how to actually clear the control itself? On another note, you could however create an extension that would remove any items first and then add the new ones instead of trying to clear the existing ones out (again, just a thought). Finally, if dealing with data from a DB, why not create an object that would hold the values you get back from the DB? Currently you are just adding individual columns to the control... probably not what you want.

Comment: Continued... If you do create an object that represents this data, you could bind a `List<myclass>` to the combo box's datasource property and set it's `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` and when the selected item changes you can get anything you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [clearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.clear) the items first:

```
this.selectAttribute.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.clear()` functionality:

```
this.selectAttribute.Items.clear()
```